# Attaching a calculated column to an existing dataframe raises TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, typeerror

I am starting to learn Pandas, and I was following the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724455/new-cumulative-value-col-derived-from-existing-col-in-a-pandas-dataframe) and could not get the solution proposed to work for me and I get an indexing error. This is what I have

```py
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
d = {'L1' : Series(['X','X','Z','X','Z','Y','Z','Y','Y',]),
     'L2' : Series([1,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,3]),
     'L3' : Series([50,100,15,200,10,1,20,10,100])}
df = DataFrame(d)  
df.groupby('L1', as_index=False).apply(lambda x : pd.expanding_sum(x.sort('L3', ascending=False)['L3'])/x['L3'].sum())
```

which outputs the following (I am using iPython)

```
L1   
X   3    0.571429
    1    0.857143
    0    1.000000
Y   8    0.900901
    7    0.990991
    5    1.000000
Z   6    0.444444
    2    0.777778
    4    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Then, I try to append the cumulative number calculation under the label "new" as suggested in the post

```py
df["new"] = df.groupby("L1", as_index=False).apply(lambda x : pd.expanding_sum(x.sort("L3", ascending=False)["L3"])/x["L3"].sum())
```

I get this:

```
   2196                         value = value.reindex(self.index).values
   2197                     except:
-> 2198                         raise TypeError('incompatible index of inserted column '
   2199                                         'with frame index')
   2200 
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Does anybody knows what the problem is? How can I reinsert the calculated value into the dataframe so it shows the values in order (descending by "new" for each label X, Y, Z.)

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using?  The above seems to work for me.

Comment: @DSM I am using pandas==0.12.0

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is, as the Error message says, that the index of the calculated column you want to insert is incompatible with the index of `df`.

The index of `df` is a simple index:

```
In [8]: df.index
Out[8]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')
```

while the index of the calculated column is a MultiIndex (as you also already can see in the output), supposing we call it `new_column`:

```
In [15]: new_column.index
Out[15]: 
MultiIndex
[(u'X', 3), (u'X', 1), (u'X', 0), (u'Y', 8), (u'Y', 7), (u'Y', 5), (u'Z', 6), (u'Z', 2), (u'Z', 4)]
```

For this reason, you cannot insert it into the frame. However, **this is a bug in 0.12**, as this does work in 0.13 (for which the answer in the linked question was tested) and the keyword `as_index=False` should ensure the column `L1` is not added to the index.

**SOLUTION for 0.12**:
Remove the first level of the MultiIndex, so you get back the original index:

```
In [13]: new_column = df.groupby('L1', as_index=False).apply(lambda x : pd.expanding_sum(x.sort('L3', ascending=False)['L3'])/x['L3'].sum())
In [14]: df["new"] = new_column.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

---

In pandas 0.13 (in development) this is fixed (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4670). It is for this reason the `as_index=False` is used in the groupby call, so the column `L1` (fow which you group) is not added to the index (creating a MultiIndex), so the original index is retained and the result can be appended to the original frame. But it seems the `as_index` keyword is ignored in 0.12 when using `apply`.

Comment: Aside: I think `df = df.sort(["L1", "L3"], ascending=[True, False]); 
df["new"] = df.groupby("L1")["L3"].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum()/x.sum())` looks a little cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

This problem still exists (as of pandas 1.5.0) if the indices don't match. A modern version of the `groupby.apply` in the OP may be written as

```py
df['new'] = df.groupby('L1')['L3'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).cumsum()/x.sum())
```

and it would raise `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`.

A solution is to drop the index level created by the `groupby`.

```py
result = df.groupby('L1')['L3'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).cumsum()/x.sum())
df['new'] = result.droplevel(0)         # <--- drop the unwanted index level
```

[image: result]

In any case, to get a column that is indexed the same as the original dataframe (as is being tried in the OP), the canonical way is to transform the function using  `groupby.transform` (as suggested by @DSM in a comment). The sorting has to be done beforehand.

```py
df['new'] = df.sort_values(by='L3', ascending=False).groupby('L1')['L3'].transform(lambda y: y.cumsum()/y.sum())
```

Yet another way is to perform the division outside the `groupby` ditching `lambda` altogether.

```py
g = df.sort_values(by='L3', ascending=False).groupby('L1')['L3']
df['new'] = g.cumsum() / g.transform('sum')
```

Comment: TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index. Is this exception because the sorted L3's index 3, 1, 0.... doesn't match the dataframe's index 0, 1, 2....?

Comment: @DavidWei the group keys are the first index level in a `groupby` result but because `sort_values` is called in `groupby.apply`, the original index is kept as the second level, which results in a MultiIndex; but the original dataframe is RangeIndex; hence the exception.