# count categorical values and add the resulting column to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, dataframe

I try to count tthe frequency of different periods of existing dataframe for every session:

```
session       time        date      period
   1         05:51:53   2015-05-22  night
   1         05:52:59   2015-05-22  night
   1         06:08:24   2015-05-22  night
   1         06:09:06   2015-05-22  night
   1         08:25:31   2015-05-22  morning
   2         08:25:35   2015-05-22  morning
   2         08:26:37   2015-05-22  morning
   2         08:27:11   2015-05-22  morning
   2         12:33:17   2015-05-22  noon
   3         12:33:45   2015-05-22  noon
```

in order to have something like:

```
session       time        date      period    frequency
   1         05:51:53   2015-05-22  night        4
   1         05:52:59   2015-05-22  night
   1         06:08:24   2015-05-22  night
   1         06:09:06   2015-05-22  night
   1         08:25:31   2015-05-22  morning      1
   2         08:25:35   2015-05-22  morning      3
   2         08:26:37   2015-05-22  morning
   2         08:27:11   2015-05-22  morning
   2         12:33:17   2015-05-22  noon         1
   3         12:33:45   2015-05-22  noon         1
```

I'm using this method

```
 df['frequency'] = df.groupby('session', as_index=False)['period'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
```

and I have this error: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

if I apply `.value_counts` directly to `groupby` as

```
 df['frequency'] = df.groupby('session', as_index=False)['period'].value_counts()
```

I have the error that `groupby` method has no attribute `value_counts`

could you advice me how can I I count these categorical values and in the same time add the resulting column to existing dataframe (I believed the `as_index=False` manage this issue but apparently not)

Comment: You want the value of frequency only for one row in the group ? Any issue if it's for all rows in the group?

Comment: I prefer one value per each value

Comment: finally this answer seems the best for the moment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192072/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-then-attach-a-calculated-column-to-an-existing

Answer (score 0):

You could `groupby` on `'session', 'period'` and find size of groups

```
In [19]: df['freq'] = df.groupby(['session', 'period'])['date'].transform(len)

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   session      time        date   period freq
0        1  05:51:53  2015-05-22    night    4
1        1  05:52:59  2015-05-22    night    4
2        1  06:08:24  2015-05-22    night    4
3        1  06:09:06  2015-05-22    night    4
4        1  08:25:31  2015-05-22  morning    1
5        2  08:25:35  2015-05-22  morning    3
6        2  08:26:37  2015-05-22  morning    3
7        2  08:27:11  2015-05-22  morning    3
8        2  12:33:17  2015-05-22     noon    1
9        3  12:33:45  2015-05-22     noon    1
```

Comment: there are some rows with missing values, so maybe it influences the result, but I have very strange results with frequency of every period over all the dataframe and not over one session

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow, doesn't this solve what you described in the question? If not, can you add more details.

Comment: no, in fact, given the big dataframe I have for ex frequency = 198 instead of 4 for every session, and in some rows of "freq" column I have date values as "2015-05-22
20
2015-05-22
2015-05-22"

Comment: with ```value_counts()``` I could count the values properly but not add it to existing dataframe and ```groupby ``` method