# Obtain mode from column in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to obtain the mode of a column in a groupby object, but I'm getting this error: `incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`.

This is the line I'm getting this on, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
dfBitSeq['KMeans'] = df.groupby('OnBitSeq')['KMeans'].apply(lambda x: x.mode())
```

Comment: Pandas mode returns a data frame unlike mean and median which return a scalar. So you just need to select the slice using x.mode().iloc[0]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Can you submit this as an answer, and I'll mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pandas mode returns a data frame unlike mean and median which return a scalar. So you just need to select the slice using x.mode().iloc[0]

```
dfBitSeq['KMeans'] = df.groupby('OnBitSeq')['KMeans'].apply(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
```

Comment: it works to me.

Comment: This was erroring for me, and instead I needed to use `df.groupby('OnBitSeq')['KMeans'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)).reset_index().drop_duplicates(['OnBitSeq']).drop(columns=['level_1'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`scipy.stats.mode`.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) Example below.

```
from scipy.stats import mode

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [2, 3], [3, 5], [2, 4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]],
                  columns=['OnBitSeq', 'KMeans'])

#    OnBitSeq  KMeans
# 0         1       5
# 1         2       3
# 2         3       5
# 3         2       4
# 4         2       3
# 5         1       4
# 6         1       5

modes = df.groupby('OnBitSeq')['KMeans'].apply(lambda x: mode(x)[0][0]).reset_index()

#    OnBitSeq  KMeans
# 0         1       5
# 1         2       3
# 2         3       5
```

If you need to add this back to the original dataframe:

```
df['Mode'] = df['OnBitSeq'].map(modes.set_index('OnBitSeq')['KMeans'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Attach a calculated column to an existing dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737811/attach-a-calculated-column-to-an-existing-dataframe).

This error looks similar and the answer is pretty useful.