# How to use groupby and sum to remove duplicate

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My dataframe has four columns: date, source, campaign and spend. Now I have duplicated value in date, source and campaign, and I wanted to sum the spend if date, source and campaign (together) is the same. So each day there will be only one source, campaign and spend

[image]

and my code is:

```
marketing_spend_dict_df['spend_update'] = 
marketing_spend_dict_df.groupby(['date','source','campaign'])['spend'].sum()
```

I get an error saying "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"
How could I deal with it? I tried to search on Google but didn't find an optimal solution
Thanks!

Comment: Would be useful if you included your sample data as text in your question instead of a linked image.

Comment: Avoid images and external links. Edit the question instead to show the table as properly formatted text.

Comment: What is `marketing_spend_dict_df`?

Comment: Checkout the answer of this.. well explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737811/attach-a-calculated-column-to-an-existing-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be due to multiindex. Checkout this link [Attach a calculated column to an existing dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737811/attach-a-calculated-column-to-an-existing-dataframe). I believe some SO user can mark it as duplicate with higher rep.

```
new_column = marketing_spend_dict_df.groupby(['date','source','campaign'], as_index=False)['spend'].sum()
marketing_spend_dict_df["spend_update"] = new_column.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```